# CSS Overflow Property Question

Tags: html, css

So I have a `<div>`. I would like to turn the css style `overflow:visible` on all content that pass through the top of the `<div>` and turn `overflow:hidden` on all content that is below the div. Is this possible?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you wrap all that is below your `<div>` in another `<div>` and make this last one `overflow:hidden`.

Does this answer your question?

Good luck!

EDIT:

Do you meen something like [this example](http://www.jsfiddle.net/muBGU/)?

Comment: thanks for the reply, the new wrapper div has the same issue as before

Comment: Thanks for the post, your idea lead me into the right direction

Comment: @No problem! Glad it helped!!

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean this

```
<style>
div { overflow:visible  } 
.Invisible { overflow:hidden } 
</style>

<div>123</div>
<div>123</div>
<div>123</div>
<div class="Invisible">Invisible</div>
```